# How to set retention policies (auto clean up) for Conan repositories

Tags: artifactory, conan

We will soon be using Artifactory for hosting Conan repositories. The packages will be created and uploaded from local developer machines and Azure Pipelines.

After looking through the JFrog documentation I have not found any sophisticated documentation nor mechanism to specify retention policies on Conan repository, user, package etc. level.

What is the most efficient and effective way to clean up unwanted Conan packages or package revisions?

Comment: Please, read and comment https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/5453, https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/3587 and https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/8418

Comment: Thank you. Will look into it.